# How to format a datatime?

Tags: python, time

I want to do uptime in python. Now my code is:

```
import datetime, time 

startTime = time.time()
ready = True

time.sleep(12)

if ready == False:
        print("i cant do that")
        return
    else:
        uptime = datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(round(time.time()-startTime)))      
        print(f"My uptime is {uptime}")
```

and output is: **`0:00:12`**. How can I get output like this: **`0d 0h 0m 12s`**?

Comment: What does the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) say? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Specifically, read about [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.datetime.strftime).